# express routes nested callback

Tags: node.js, express, callback, routes

I'm newer in express, deploying a express app. i'd like to call a function checkApiKey before every api called. here is my API routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fn = require('../webservices');
router.post('/api/signup',fn.checkApiKey, fn.signup);
module.exports = router;
```

and here my webservice.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');
var db =  require('./conn')
var models =  require('./models')

function signup(req, res, next){
  var postData  = req.body;
  console.log('signup called', postData);
  checkApiKey(req, res, function(err, done){
    models.user.save(postData, function(err, saved) {
      console.log('err', err);
      if(err) return res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", message: 'Server Error' });
      return res.status(200).json({ status: "success", data:saved, message: 'Success' });
    })
  })
}

function checkApiKey(req, res, next){
  console.log('checkApiKey called');
  if(req.body.apiKey!='123') return res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", message: 'ApiKey not Match' });
  return next(req, res);
}

module.exports = {
  signup, checkApiKey
}
```

here checkApiKey called but signup not called error status 500 while removing fn.checkApiKey then signup successfull also when i use

```
router.post('/api/signup',function (req, res, next){
  console.log('checkApiKey called');
  if(req.body.apiKey!='123') return res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", message: 'ApiKey not Match' });
  return fn.signup(req, res);
});
```

this works but i need to write code every time for each api 
can anyone help me to find out correct way

Answer (score 2):

Because express is a middleware you can make the checkAPikey in every request by adding the following code as imran said:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.apiKey!='123') return res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", message: 'ApiKey not Match' });
    next(req, res);
})
```

You will see similar code in app.js or server.js where by default it's established the body-parser package (when you generate the skeleton via express-generator for instance).

If you put that code in app.js, first it will go to the code shared on the top and then to your request via next().

Answer (score 1):

You're using `module.exports` wrong. It should be:

```
module.exports = {
  signup: signup,
  checkApiKey: checkApiKey
}
```

Also take `checkApiKey` out of your `signup` middleware:

```
function signup(req, res, next){
  var postData  = req.body;

  models.user.save(postData, function(err, saved) {
    if(err) return res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", message: 'Server Error' });
    return res.status(200).json({ status: "success", data:saved, message: 'Success' });
 })
}
```

Then this should work fine:

```
var fn = require('../webservices');
router.post('/api/signup', fn.checkApiKey, fn.signup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
var app = express();

app.use(checkApiKey);

it will call on before each call..